# Tracking / Click Actvity / Email Overlay View

Tags: marketing-cloud

When I check the click activity, the overlay view does not show the percentages for some of the links for the email. Has anyone else encountered this issue and (or) has a fix for it?

Comment: Did you get any clicks and can share a screenshot of the issue, please?

Comment: Not sure how I can share a screen shot (It has client info). I am getting some clicks on the footers, headers and social share icons. The body has link (large hyperlinked images) which are not getting click information displayed. however, this information is displayed below and in the link view. Hope this helps

Comment: Is the hypertext linked image in a dynamic content area? Hard to help secret squirrels and the client information they've shared with a close crowd of a few hundred thousand other secret squirrels.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMcLeod. The links are not dynamic per se, but do have Ampscript personalization . This squirrel would very much like to keep his job :)

Comment: Haha! I do understand. So, AMPScript... You appending variables to a URL? What does the anchor tag in the content look like?

Comment: <a href="%%=redirectTo(concat('http://www.website.com/',@siteid,'/More/links', @analyticTags))=%%" target="_blank"> is an example of a link that would did not render on the Email Overlay. Thanks alot for your help Andrew!

Comment: Mmmm. I think you're going to struggle getting the overlay to work with the @siteid part of the path. The RedirectTo... It's all correct given the URL you're building. The RedirectTo's going to be breaking the overlay, though. I don't think it will solve it, but can you try adding an "Alias" attribute to the anchor tag. It's a long shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a dynamically generated URL that you're populating the anchor tag with, providing an alias attribute for the tag may solve your issue with displaying the link in the overlay view:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%" alias="banner_image_link">...</a>
```